How to create a horizontally scrollable grid with responsive items in CSS?
I'm trying to create a horizontally scrollable container with items arranged in a grid layout. I want the items to adapt to the screen width, allowing for horizontal scrolling when there are too many items to fit on one screen. Additionally, I need to control the number of rows or the height of the container.
<div ref={ref} className="emojiList">
    {emojis.map((emoji) => (
        <Emoji key={emoji.id} emoji={emoji} />
    ))}
</div>

.emojiList {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    justify-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    padding: $padding;
    gap: $gap;
    background: $palette-white;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

Design

I've tried flexbox, grid, scroll snap, but couldn't achieve this. I'm down for using any library if you can offer.

Please edit your question to show us what you have tried. We need to see what you have tried to help us determine whether you are on the right track and just made a syntax error, or whether you are using the wrong approach. You also need to be really clear when you describe exactly what you are trying to achieve and the constraints you are working within. Note that we are not a code-writing service, that's why we don't just accept a statement like "I've tried everything, but it doesn't work".

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
